# Find Heisenberg evolution (matrix products with complex numbers)

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

> We will study the time-evolution of a finite dimensional quantum system. To this end, let us consider a quantum mechanical system with the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$. We denote by $\left . \left |   0  \right \rangle\right .$ and $\left . \left |   1  \right \rangle\right .$ the standard basis elements $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$. Let the Hamiltonian of the system in this basis be given by
> $$
> H=\omega\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &1 \\ 
> 1 &0 
> \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &-i \\ 
> -i &0 
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
> and assume that for $t=0$ the state of the system is just given by $\psi(t=0)=\left . \left |   0  \right \rangle\right .$. In the following, we also assume natural units in which $\hbar=1$.

I have found that  $\psi(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\\ 
-\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}.$

And I have computed  the expectation value of $\left \langle \sigma_z \right \rangle_{\psi(t)}=\left \langle \psi(t)\mid \sigma_z\psi(t) \right \rangle$ where  $
\sigma_z=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 &-1 
\end{pmatrix}$ to 1.

Now I have to determine the time-evolved observable $\sigma_z=e^{iHt}\sigma_ze^{-iHt}$ (the Heisenberg evolution of $\sigma_z$) and I have to determine the resulting expectation value $\langle \sigma_z(t)\rangle_{\psi_0}=\langle\psi_0|\sigma_z(t)\psi_0\rangle$. But I'm not sure how to deal with it? Is the first one just a matrix product I have to solve? But what is $e^{iHt}$ then? I hope anyone can help me?

Comment: Not sure what you wrote is the evolution operator...

Comment: Have I done something wrong while finding  the evolution operator? I have just the solution: $$x(t)=c_1\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}e^{1t}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}e^{-1t}$$?  while I have found the eigenvalues to 1 and -1 and it's possible then to find $c_1=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $c_2=\frac{1}{2}$? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Or it's just $\psi(t)$ I have found?

Comment: :) Yes, it's $\psi(t)$

Comment: Can you so please help me how to use $\psi(t)$ to find $U(t)$  then?

Comment: I add some to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e^{iHt}$ is $U^*(t)$, is the conjugate transpose of $U(t)$ <del>(you can calculate $e^{iHt}$ to check this)</del>

With $\hat\sigma_z=e^{iHt}\sigma_ze^{-iHt}$ and $\mid\psi(t)\rangle=e^{-iHt}\mid\psi_0\rangle,\;\langle\psi(t)\mid=\langle\psi_0\mid e^{iHt}$

this identity follows,

$\left \langle \sigma_z \right \rangle_{\psi(t)}=\left \langle \psi(t)\mid \sigma_z \mid \psi(t) \right \rangle=$

$=\left \langle\psi_0\mid e^{iHt}\sigma_z e^{-iHt}\mid\psi_0 \right \rangle=$

$=\left \langle\psi_0\mid\hat\sigma_z\mid\psi_0 \right \rangle$

ADDED:

$U(t)=e^{-iHt}$ is the solution to the Schrodinger (differential) equation and it is the evolution operator (acting over $\mid\psi_0\rangle$ to give the state in any moment). The calculation of the exponential operator is not difficult, but some cumbersome. I [tricked an online tool to do that](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-exponential-calculator/e%5E%7B%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D0%26-3%5C%5C%20%20-3%260%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%7D?or=input). Follow the link to see how it's done.

Anyway, $U(t)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}&-\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\\ 
-\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}&\frac{1}{2}e^{t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}.$

EDIT:

The Hamiltonian is not self-adjoint, so $U^*\neq U^{-1}$. It's still true that $U^{-1}=e^{iHt}$. My response is valid in the case it was.

I only can speculate about what happened. Probably $H=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\ 
1&0
\end{pmatrix}$ originally.

Comment: Hey @Rafa I'm not sure but will the calculations be:$$=\left \langle\psi_0\mid\hat\sigma_z\mid\psi_0 \right \rangle= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=1$$ Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: No, actually it's not constant. In fact, it's the time dependent expected value calculated using the Heisemberg point of view. Use $U(t),U^{-1}(t)$ and $\sigma_z$ (operator for Schrôdinger point of view) to get $\hat\sigma_z$ (operator for the Heisemberg point of view).  You can perform the calculations anyway, but be aware that your Hamiltonian is not self-adjoint (as it had to be).